# If I compile a C/C++ program on a linux machine, does it automatically have rwx perms

Tags: c, linux, security, penetration-testing

I am currently learning penetration testing as part of a cybersecurity career path. I was working on a vulnhub machine that required me writing some malware to exploit a buffer overflow bug. I decided to write it in C for the sake of practicing OpSec. I used code::blocks on my machine to write the code and used tcp to transfer the compiled app to the machine. Once I tried to run it, I found that it did not have execute permissions, and the compromised user account did not have permission to use chmod, however it did have permission to use GCC. I was wondering if I uploaded the code directly to the machine and compiled it natively, would the app have execute permissions?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66503/how-does-gcc-handle-file-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, `rsync` would be able to retain file permission when transferring between machines, maybe give it a try?

From local machine: `rsync -aP source_path remote_machine:destination_path`

`-a` is archive mode, preserves file properties

`-P` shows progress